# How can I fetch a list of file names from a Remote Server via FTP?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I need to display the file names in a webpage using PHP FTP, and the list has to be sorted by the timestamp. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need:

1. Start connection with FTP server (ftp_connect).
2. Login to FTP (ftp_login).
3. Get list of files (ftp_nlist).
4. Get timestamp for each file (ftp_mdtm).
5. Sort files by timpestamp and exclude folders.

Please see my code example:

```
<?php
define('FTP_URL', '');
define('FTP_USERNAME', '');
define('FTP_PASSWORD', '');
define('FTP_DIRECTORY', '');

//Connect ot FTP
$ftp = ftp_connect(FTP_URL);
//Login to FTP
ftp_login($ftp, FTP_USERNAME, FTP_PASSWORD);
//Get files
$filesAndFolders = ftp_nlist($ftp, FTP_DIRECTORY);
$dates = array();
$files = array();
foreach ($filesAndFolders as $key => $file) {
    //Get date
    $date = ftp_mdtm($ftp , $file);
    if ($date !== -1) {//Filter folders
        $files[] =  $file;
        $dates[] = $date;
    }
}
//Sort files by date
array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $files);

//Render files list
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo '<li>' . $file . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```